# Angular Cloudinary not setting alt tags

Tags: angular, cloudinary

I hope someone can help me with this.
I am using Cloudinary for our image needs and because we are using Angular, we are using the Cloudinary Angular SDK:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_image_manipulation

Our social media manager has gone through all the images and added Titles and Descriptions (alt) and I thought that all of our images on the website would automatically pull down the alt tags, but that is not happening.

I cannot find any documentation talking about how to use the alt tags stored in cloudinary and because our images are served through a headless CMS, there is no way for me to set them. Has anyone else experienced this issue and know how to get the alt tags (and preferably titles too) to appear on the img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `alt` value you can:

- Call the [list by tag API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_url_delivery_options#client_side_resources) if you just have a client-side application
- extract the alt from the [Admin API resources method](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources) if the data is coming from the server-side.

Here is a fiddle showing the  client-side list by tag and accessing the `alt` metadata: https://jsfiddle.net/62L3yzk0/1/

If you directly access this URL: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/list/logo.json you will see all the images tagged as logo. The last one is the google image one and has an alt element set to `google logo` which is then set as the `alt` element in the fiddle.

Another option would be to periodically synchronize those metadata to your database and then use on your client-side code.